# Calling a method in another thread after a thread is finished

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing

I'm trying to parallelize my program, but since I'm very new to threads, I'm facing some problems.

I have two methods which are part of the same class. One of the methods does some calculations in a for loop and pushes the results in a vector, other method (runTheResult) takes the vector and launches a thread using the obtained vector. I wish to launch another thread for running the next obtained result every time runTheResult is done with a result while limiting the maximum number of threads at a time to 4.

The structure of my program is like:

```
void runTheResult(vector<double>& u){

//process 'u' and launch a thread 


};

void method(){

for(...){

//calculate

    for(...){

    //put the calculations in vector<double>result

    };

    runTheResult(result); 

};

};
```

I've googled about this a lot and one of the solutions is to maintain a message que. The problem with this, however, is if I implement a que, I'll have to check the que with another thread periodically in a while loop. If I use while loop like `while(true){//check for new messages if number of threads is less than five}`, I'll lose a lot of processing power and if I choose to put the loop to sleep if condition is not met, I waste processing power. The functions I'm running in threads take 2-5 seconds each and I've to process ~1k to 50k of them so even a second of delay per loop is a lot.

Is it possible to run runTheResultin another thread every time runTheResult is done? or is there better way to do this?

Comment: You can have the other thread waiting for a condition variable and awake on that, then execute the function you want based on some flags you will have set. In Windows, you can also have a message queue and post a message (not the for loop you have created, but GetMessage()). For simple multithreading calculations you can also use future/promise.

Comment: Create 4 threads and let them wait for a condition variable. Every time you have work ready for one of the threads, call `notify_one`.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis If i check for the flags, I'll still have to use while loop though, right? If you don't mind, could you elaborate please more?

Comment: The point is that, by using these "waiting" objects, the for loop won't consume system resources. If you wait on the condition variable, then while waiting the thread won't eat the CPU. You will do a for loop, but inside that you would be checking for the condition variable, and if it's set, *then* check the flags.

Comment: Some more info in one of my older articles [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/540912/Cplusplus-11-Threads-Make-your-multitasking-life-e).

Comment: You can use condition variables to synchronize the threads. If you are working on linux you can use pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal functions to achieve

Comment: Often, the _best_ way to ensure that certain things happen in a certain order is to do all of those things in a single thread. E.g., if you want to do a, then b, then c; write `a(...); b(...); c(...);`. You say that you want to do things in different threads, but why? Your example shows some structure from your program, but it doesn't help anybody to understand what problem you actually are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others are telling you to use message queue because that's the safest way to do it. Your program must have at least a main thread that the user(you or end-user) can interact with. This main thread will be looping for as long as your program runs. You do your message processing here

```
// this is not actually running the result now
// this only sends it to the main thread that will run the result
void runTheResult(vector<double>& u){ 

    //process 'u' and launch a thread. 
    // @NOTE Launching a thread again will not be beneficial as it will still be blocked 
    // by the mutex

    // convert/store vector into Message. To make it usable for other types
    // or you can just change Message to double
    Message u_message = to_message(u)

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(message_mutex);
    messages_shared.append(u_message);

};

void method() // runs on worker thread
{
    for(...){

    //put the calculations in vector<double>result

    };

    runTheResult(result);
}

void getMessages_safe(std::vector<Messages>& outMessages_safe)
{
    // as Ted Lyngo suggests, using lock_guard is best practice. See edit for alternative
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(message_mutex);
    outMessages_safe = messages_shared;
    messages_shared.clear();
}

std::vector<Message> messages_shared;
std::mutex message_mutex;

void main() { // this runs on the very first thread of the program
  while (isProgramRunning)
  {
      std::vector<Message> messages_safe; // safe to access by this thread only
      getMessages_safe(messages_safe);

      // dispatch messages to whoever needs it

      // launch worker thread
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a proper guard for the mutex? If `messages_shared.append()` throws, the mutex will be locked forever if you do like above. `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(message_mutex); messages_shared.append(u_message);` and then you don't need to manually unlock it. It also looks like noone is waiting for a condition variable so at least one thread will be spinning like crazy.

Comment: That's true. But as it's not the main topic of the question. I used the most explicit way to use mutex, because I don't know if the op knows about it.

Comment: OP seemed pretty concerned about performance so wasting a processor on spinning when it could be doing other things (like tending to the OS) won't do well.  Also, lock guards and condition variables is almost a must when dealing with threads so I'm sure OP will pick up on what they are good for if you bring them into your example.

Comment: I've edited my answer to use `lock_guard`. But I can't think of a way to implement conditional variable without making the program a single execution program with no way of starting up new threads later on.

Comment: Good. About `condition_variable`s When someone puts a message in `messages_shared` it could `notify_one` and the main thread could wait on that instead of trying to fetch messages that aren't there over and over again.

Comment: I've thought about that. But if all the worker threads finishes, then the program will be idle forever. Unless there's some kind of way to send an event to this program without a spinning thread, then I'll just stick with my answer because if I put that, the practicality of my answer will be lost.

Comment: Well, you have made a message queue so that'd be one way to communicate, or the queue could have a shutdown flag associated with it etc.

Comment: But then the sender of that message would have to be spinning continuously too right? Why not just do it here.

Comment: No, it woulden't. You already have most of the basic stuff in place. `messages_shared.append()` + `notify_one`. Only the main process is interested in extracting from `messages_shared` and would have to wait for that notification.

Comment: Yeah I see now what you mean, I'm sure op is interested in the use of conditional variable. But this is as far as my answer could go.

Comment: Fair enough :-)